# How to Get Email Addresses of Feedburner Subscribers

Tags: feedburner

I setup Feedburner on my Wordpress blogs. I want to retrieve the email addresses of my subscribers. But I couldn't find a way to get these addresses from Feedburner.

I made some [googling](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=Manage+Your+Email+Subscriber+List+feedburner&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) before asking. There are some tutorials to retrieve email addresses but on my Feedburner account there is no "Manage your list of email subscribers" link.

Should I better use  [Mailpress](http://www.mailpress.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) instead of Feedburner?

Answer (score 3):

In FeedBurner (old interface, don't know about new one - it was too beta last time I tried):

1. Click feed
2. `Publicize` tab
3. `Email Subscirptions` in `Services` menu
4. `View Subscriber Details` at the bottom of the page.
5. `Export: CSV` option or just take a look.

Comment: Thank you. This works. I wonder why do they hide this information below so many links.

Comment: Thank you - very helpful! I don't find feedburner at all intuitive so your instructions were just what I needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Manage your list of email subscribers link is hidden and you have work a bit to get it.

1. Log in to your feedburner account.
2. Click the title of your feed.
3. Below of your feed title, you can find the link that says, “Edit Feed Details” then click that link.
4. On this page, you can see your feed status. Scroll down a little bet and you can see the link the says, “See more about your subscribers >>”. Click that link.
5. On this page you can see the diagram of your feed status. Scroll a little bet and you find the Email Subscription Services. Below that you can find the link that says, “FeedBurner Email Subscriptions. Click that link.
6. After doing the step 5 you can find a link that says, “Manage Your Email Subscriber List” then click that link.
7. On this page, you now finally see your email subscriber list and their status using FeedBurner. You can also see when they subscribe to your blog.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. "Email Subscription Services" and "FeedBurner Email Subscriptions" links on step 5 are not existing in my Feedburner account. It is weird that the interface changes according to the user.